# Assign different aggregation functions to different features in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I have a data like below (Instead of 4 columns I have 100 columns)

```
raw_data = { 
        'age': [52, 52, 24, 24, 24], 
        'a': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3],
        'b': [3, 2, 3, 4, 3],
        'c': [2, 5, 8, 2, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = [ 'age', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
```

which results in

```
    age a   b   c
0   52  4   3   2
1   52  24  2   5
2   24  31  3   8
3   24  2   4   2
4   24  3   3   1
```

I want to group data by age and find mean of some features and sum of remaining features. I have tried this:

```
feats = ['a', 'b']
df.groupby('age').agg({feats:['mean'], 'c':['sum']})
```

Since I have 100 features in real data, I cannot assign functions (I have multiple functions to assign: RMS, Kurtosis, Energy Index, etc) to individual feature (I can but it is very time consuming and not smart) Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: So, of those 100 features, is there any pattern to which you want to sum and which you want the mean?  You can use dictionary comprehension and some filtering logic to create an aggregation dictionary.

Comment: @ScottBoston I have sensor features and event codes. I would like to find the mean of sensor features and the sum of event codes. But, a dictionary is a good idea. I will try that. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use dictionary comprehension.

```
agg_d = {i:'mean' for i in feats}
agg_d['c'] = 'sum'

df.groupby('age').agg(agg_d)
```

Output:

```
      a         b   c
age                  
24   12  3.333333  11
52   14  2.500000   7
```

Update, and you can use multiple aggregation function using a list:

```
agg_d = {i:['sum','max','first', lambda x: sum(x**2)] for i in feats}
agg_d['c'] = 'sum'
```

Comment: Thanks and gig'em fellow Aggie :) What should I do if I have multiple functions instead of one?

Comment: @ArchDesai Gig'em!  You can use a list instead of 'mean' like this `agg_d = {i:['sum','max','first',lambda x: x**2] for i in feats}`

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I was looking for. I accepted the answer. Could you edit your answer please to this (sorry, I added multiple functions in question later)?

Comment: @Scott Boston, when applying above agg_d: `ValueError: Must produce aggregated value`. Maybe should be `agg_d = {i:['sum','max','first', lambda x: sum(x**2)] for i in feats}` ?

Comment: @lpj... Oops, you are correct.  Good correction.  Thank you!